# JavaFX: Stage close handler

Tags: java, javafx, handler, javafx-8

I want to save a file before closing my JavaFX application.

This is how I'm setting up the handler in `Main::start`:

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    System.out.println("Stage is closing");
    // Save file
});
```

And the controller calling `Stage::close` when a button is pressed:

```
@FXML
public void exitApplication(ActionEvent event) {
    ((Stage)rootPane.getScene().getWindow()).close();
}
```

If I close the window clicking the red X on the window border (the normal way) then I get the output message "`Stage is closing`", which is the desired behavior.

However, when calling `Controller::exitApplication` the application closes without invoking the handler (there's no output).

How can I make the controller use the handler I've added to `primaryStage`?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you have a look at the [life-cycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) of the `Application` class:

> The JavaFX runtime does the following, in order, whenever an
>   application is launched:
>
> 1. Constructs an instance of the specified Application class
> 2. Calls the `init()` method
> 3. Calls the `start(javafx.stage.Stage)` method
> 4. Waits for the application to finish, which happens when either of the following occur:
>
>    - the application calls `Platform.exit()`
>    - the last window has been closed and the `implicitExit` attribute on `Platform` is `true`
> 5. Calls the `stop()` method

This means you can call `Platform.exit()` on your controller:

```
@FXML
public void exitApplication(ActionEvent event) {
   Platform.exit();
}
```

as long as you override the `stop()` method on the main class to save the file.

```
@Override
public void stop(){
    System.out.println("Stage is closing");
    // Save file
}
```

As you can see, by using `stop()` you don't need to listen to close requests to save the file anymore (though you can do it if you want to prevent window closing).

Answer (score 16):

Suppose you want to ask the user if he want to exit the application without saving the work. If the user choose no, you cannot avoid the application to close within the stop method. In this case you should **add an EventFilter to your window** for an WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST event.

In your start method add this code to detect the event:

(Note that ***calling Platform.exit(); doesn't fire the WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST event***, see below to know how to fire the event manually from a custom button)

```
// *** Only for Java >= 8 ****
// ==== This code detects when an user want to close the application either with
// ==== the default OS close button or with a custom close button ====

primaryStage.getScene().getWindow().addEventFilter(WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST, this::closeWindowEvent);
```

Then add your custom logic. In my example i use an Alert popup to ask the user if he/she want to close the application without saving.

```
private void closeWindowEvent(WindowEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Window close request ...");

        if(storageModel.dataSetChanged()) {  // if the dataset has changed, alert the user with a popup
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.getButtonTypes().remove(ButtonType.OK);
            alert.getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
            alert.getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.YES);
            alert.setTitle("Quit application");
            alert.setContentText(String.format("Close without saving?"));
            alert.initOwner(primaryStage.getOwner());
            Optional<ButtonType> res = alert.showAndWait();

            if(res.isPresent()) {
                if(res.get().equals(ButtonType.CANCEL))
                    event.consume();
            }
        }
    }
```

The `event.consume()` method **prevents the application from closing**. Obviously you should add at least a button that permit the user to close the application to avoid the force close application by the user, that in some cases can corrupt data.

Lastly, if you have to **fire the event** from a custom close button, you can use this :

```
Window window = Main.getPrimaryStage()  // Get the primary stage from your Application class
                .getScene()
                .getWindow();

window.fireEvent(new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST));
```

Comment: Very useful for my use case, where I have a simple dialog and am not subclassing the Application class.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh this is a known bug in JavaFX where the Stage will not close if a modal dialog is present at the time of closing. I will link you to the bug report which I just saw today. I *think* it is fixed in the latest release.

Here you go:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8093147?jql=text%20~%20%22javafx%20re-entrant%22

resolved in 8.4 it says. I think this what you are describing.

Answer (score -1):

```
public Stage getParentStage() {
    return (Stage) getFxmlNode().getScene().getWindow();
}

btnCancel.setOnAction(e -> {
    getParentStage().close();
});
```

Comment: good that you tried to be helpful - but this doesn't solve the problem of the OP: there is no button ;)