# JavaFX - Automatically show alert box after closing it

Tags: java, events, javafx

I want to automatically show an alert box again after closing it, this is based on a certain condition.
Here's my code:

```
protected void showInputDialog()
{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("AddRecordDialog.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    AddRecordDialogController addRecordDialogController = (AddRecordDialogController)loader.getController();
    addRecordDialogController.setAddNewSalesDialogController(this);
    addRecordDialogController.setInvoice(this.invoice);
    this.addRecordDialog = new Stage();
    this.addRecordDialog.setTitle("Add Record");
    this.addRecordDialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    this.addRecordDialog.initOwner(root.getScene().getWindow());
    this.addRecordDialog.setScene(scene);
    this.addRecordDialog.sizeToScene();
    this.addRecordDialog.setResizable(false);
    //Event handler for when a Window is closed.
    this.addRecordDialog.setOnHiding(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent we)
        {
            if(nextItem == true)
               showInputDialog();
            nextItem = false;
        }
    });
    this.addRecordDialog.showAndWait();
}
```

The second dialog shows up but the first dialog doesn't disappear.
The dialog is programmatically closed with a `stage.close();` somewhere else.
I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548460/javafx-stage-close-event-handler) that you need to call the `setOnHiding` method for a programmatically closing event.
If I remove the event handler the previous stage will close.
But I want to open a new instance of that stage again after it is closed.
Please help.

**Edit:** ...yes I checked for the `nextItem` variable it was `true`,

I used `System.out.println("Next Item: " + nextItem);`

Comment: `onHiding` is called prior to the Window being hidden.  `onHidden` is called after the Window has been hidden. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onHiddenProperty

Comment: Thanks it has worked. @kendavidson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [kendavidson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4196620/kendavidson)'s comment, I have found the solution.
I've changed the code to:

```
        this.addRecordDialog.setOnHidden(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent we)
            {
                System.out.println("Next Item: " + nextItem);
                if(nextItem == true)
                {
                    nextItem = false;
                    showInputDialog();
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks kendavidson.