# Why JavaFX application Task Manager process doesn't end when closed

Tags: java, javafx

For some reason there are processes in my app that continue even after closing the application's window and exiting. Is there something I haven't accounted for? My app periodically generates a system tray notification, but these continue even after exiting. The only way to stop it is to find the java.exe process in the Task Manager. Is there something I'm overlooking?

```
public class TrayNotification {

    public static void execute(String firstName, String incidentNumber, String requestId, TableView tabTable) throws AWTException, MalformedURLException {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            TrayNotification trayNotification = new TrayNotification();
            trayNotification.displayTray(firstName, incidentNumber, requestId, tabTable);
        }
    }

    private void displayTray(String firstName, String incidentNumber, String requestId, TableView tabTable) throws AWTException, MalformedURLException {
        // Obtain a single instance of SystemTray
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        // Set TrayIcon values
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("/images/tray-icon.png"));
        final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Remedy React Notification");
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        trayIcon.setToolTip(incidentNumber);

        // Add TrayIcon to SystemTray instance if possible
        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // System.out.println("Notification could not be added.");
        }

        trayIcon.addActionListener(e -> {
            Parent root = null;
            try {
                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/scene.fxml"));
                root.requestLayout();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Test");
        });

        // Display TrayIcon 
            trayIcon.displayMessage("Hey, " + firstName, "You are now tracking " + incidentNumber + " !", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);

    }

}
```

Comment: Most probable cause is the creation of non-daemon threads. Are you creating any new threads in your program, either explicitly or through a executor? Consider trying to provide an [MCVE].

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2213340/230513) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.8).

Answer (score 1):

I am using `System.exit(0)` when the user clicks "Exit" button.

Comment: My problem is I don't have kind of handler that specifies the window's "exit" button. I don't have an Exit menu item and won't be implementing one... I think I need something along the lines of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619566/javafx-stage-close-handler

Comment: @santafebound - If you don't have an "Exit" option, how do you define "exiting"? You said "these continue even after exiting" - at the point of "exiting", calling `System.exit(0)` should terminate the JVM instance.

Comment: Are you using the [X] on the top left/right corner to exit the application?