# How to get column width and name when resized a column in a tableview in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I need to save column width in user-settings file that i cloud load the TableView with the same width of each column that user previously given for better user experience.

In my research there is a listener on change in width property

```
tcName.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {});
```

Where "tcName" is column object.

this is firing several times in a raw while changing the column width.

is there any event called changed ?
Or

any possiblility to get output like below

```
@FXML
private TableView<ItemEmployee> tvData;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ItemEmployee, String> tcCode;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ItemEmployee, String> tcName;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ItemEmployee, String> tcCompany;

tcCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Code"));
tcName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("FullName"));
tcCompany.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("CompanyName"));

tvData.columnWidthChanged(){
    system.out.println("width changed column name: tcCode/Code " );
    system.out.println("width of column tcCode/Code : 150" );
    saveColumnWidth("tcCode/Code",150);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create a boolean variable with default value of false

```
boolean isUIUpdatedByUser = false;
```

2.in your

```
tcName.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
      isUIUpdatedByUser = true; // just set it to true
  });
```

3. Now handle the close event. there are number of ways to handle the scene close event.e.g. 
   a) Give an Id to your AnchorPane and get the close event like

   ap.getScene().getWindow().setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
       });

   b) where you add your stage

   primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {

   ```
   });
   ```

   c) see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620713/2299040)
4. Now in your close event.

   {
    //Save your ui changes
    saveColumnWidth("tcCode/Code",150);
   }

To ease the task of handling multiple columns width. 
You can do the following

1. create a Anonymous class

// create a listener

```
final ChangeListener<Number> listener = new ChangeListener<Number>()
{

  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, final Number newValue)
  {
      //do your code here
  }
};
```

and use it like

```
column1.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
column2.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
```

2. Create a common function add call it

   public void changelistener(final TableColumn listerColumn) {
           listerColumn.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

   ```
           @Override
           public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
               System.out.print(listerColumn.getText() + "  ");
               System.out.println(t1);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

User it like

```
changelistener(column1);
        changelistener(column2);
        changelistener(column3);
```

Comment: Thanks bro for the grate snippet, is there any way to listen the TableView rather that the column. (yes of course, I need to know the column is resized or not)

Comment: @Labeeb I have updated my answer to help you ease with multiple column width change handling. If this answer fits your need. please accept the answer :)